# Android и MySQL соединение

Tags: android, mysql

пишу мобильное приложение, которое должно получать данные из СУБД MySQL.

Какие способы существуют для соединения MySQL с Android, и какой из них наиболее оптимальный?

Для SQLite есть свой класс, а нету класса для работы с удаленными СУБД?

Comment: Напишите свой API на бэкенде для приложения.

Comment: @Например на PHP?Это единственный способ?

Comment: Самый логичный способ. Способов бэкенд написать много, и php далеко не самый лучший вариант.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin какой вы считаете более лучшим?

Comment: @danilshik node.js

Comment: @Suvitruf кхм-кхм вряд ли. И вопрос очень субъективный и холиварный, потому не советовал бы вообще на него отвечать.

Comment: Вообще да, Android приложение может напрямую работать с MySQL с помощью jdbc. Но это делать КРАЙНЕ не рекомендуется. Если это для лабы или курсовой, то ещё ладно, но в реальном приложении не надо этого делать.

Comment: Используй SQLite или Realm они больше подходят для Android

Comment: SQLite же встроенная СУБД

Comment: а для удаленной БД тебе нужно писать какой никакой бекенд .

Comment: У меня данные постоянно обновляются. Как я понимаю понятие "встроенная" - это СУБД , которая находится на устройстве для работы с данными без Интернета. И чтобы изменить данные в БД придется обновлять приложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с MySQL напрямую можно использовать jdbc из пакета `java.sql`.

Но это **КРАЙНЕ НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ** из-за проблем с безопасностью. Если вы это пишете в учебных целях, то ещё ладно, но в реальных приложениях не нужно этого делать. Все порты для таких систем должны быть закрыты и доступ должен осуществляться через специально написанные сервисы.